# Why does a piece of R code does not work during Knit in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, dplyr, knitr, ggcorrplot

When Knitting ans Rmarkdown (R Studio) document containing chunks of R code a chunck returns

```
line 192 Error in stats::hclust(dd, method=hc.method) :
  must have n>= 2 objects to cluster Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval -> ggcorrplot -> .hc_cormat_order -> <Anonymous>
```

Same piece of code runs fine when run in R (R Studio) and runs from within markdown. This only happens during Knit!

Made no significant changes code in chunk is copy/paste from R-file. Added `cache=FALSE` and `echo=FALSE`. Didn't help.
Did put every line in separate chunk. This showed the error not to be at the `library (dplyr)` line but at the actual `ggcorrplot` line

```
library(dplyr)
dfNed_2b <- dfNed_2a %>% dplyr:: select(grep("GDP", names(dfNed_2a)), grep("GDY", names(dfNed_2a)), grep("GNP", names(dfNed_2a)))
dfNed_2b[is.na(dfNed_2b)] <- 0
corrNed_2b <- round(cor(dfNed_2b), 4)
library(ggcorrplot)
ggcorrplot(corrNed_2b, hc.order = TRUE, 
           type = "lower", 
           lab = TRUE, 
           lab_size = 2, 
           method="circle",
           tl.cex=7,
           colors = c("orangered1", "white", "darkolivegreen1"), 
           title="Correlogram GDP, GDY en GNP indicatoren", 
           ggtheme=theme_minimal)
```

From the R code I get a great Correlogram. The knit in Rmd returns:

```
line 192 Error in stats::hclust(dd, method=hc.method) :
must have n>= 2 objects to cluster Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval -> ggcorrplot -> .hc_cormat_order -> <Anonymous>
```

Error seem to refer back to first line in chunk while actual error is on the `ggcorrplot` line(s)

==================================================
Error still seems to persist. Changed Rmd to only use external R scripts
Rmd:
        ### *Correlatie plot van de GDP, GDY en GNP indicatoren*
        `{r cache=FALSE}
        knitr::read_chunk('6e_corr_dfNed_2b.R')`

````
    ```{r 6e_corr_dfNed_2b}
    ```
````

R:
        ## ---- 6e_corr_dfNed_2b
        library(dplyr)
        dfNed_2c <- dfNed_2b %>% dplyr::select(grep("GDP", names(dfNed_2b)), 
        grep("GDY", names(dfNed_2b)), grep("GNP", names(dfNed_2b)))
        dfNed_2c[is.na(dfNed_2c)] <- 0
        head(dfNed_2c,2)
        library(ggplot2)
        library(scales)
        library(ggcorrplot)
        corrNed_2c <- round(cor(dfNed_2c), 4)
        ggcorrplot(corrNed_2c, hc.order = TRUE, 
                   type = "lower", 
                   lab = TRUE, 
                   lab_size = 2, 
                   method="circle",
                   tl.cex=7,
                   colors = c("orangered1", "white", "darkolivegreen1"), 
                   title="Correlogram GDP, GDY en GNP indicatoren", 
                   ggtheme=theme_minimal)

Only thing I can think of is that Knitr does like the library(dplyr) being used in aprevious chunk. Thought that was tackled by the cache=FALSE

Comment: Where did you create `dfNed_2a`? `Rmarkdown` evaluates code in a completely new session. It does not know about objects currently in your environment.

Comment: If you don't want to create `dfNed_2a` while knitting (e.g., if it takes too long), you can run `rmarkdown::render(your_markdown_file.Rmd)` in R.

Comment: Based on the first reply (JBGruber) I cleared my workspace and Global environment and ran my Rmd from the top (code shown is only small part). This did the trick and Rmd was Knitted succesfully. I most likely mixed execution of R code and Rmd with r-code in it. THNX!

Comment: Do I need to close this issue? How?

Comment: Problem still persists. I have rebuild my Rmd to only have external R scripts like follows:   
Rmd: ### *Correlatie plot van de GDP, GDY en GNP indicatoren*   
```{r cache=FALSE}
knitr::read_chunk('6e_corr_dfNed_2b.R')
```
   
```{r 6e_corr_dfNed_2b}
```